# iPad using iPhone storyboard instead of iPad storyboard on iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I'm developing an universal iOS app, so I've created two storyboards, one for iPhone and one for iPad.
Everythings works fine in iOS 7
but the iPad with iOS6 keeps using the iPhone storyboard, stretched as an iPad layout, like it's a native iPad storyboard (not with the 2x button on the screen)..

Can anyone help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the "Main Interface" under iPad is set to your iPad storyboard,

[image]